# SQL Query in Access missing operator syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi i created a database in Microsoft Access and i have been trying to find specific stuff through query's but when i try to test my query i keep getting a syntax error saying i miss an operator this is my query:

```
SELECT student.name
FROM institution 
    INNER JOIN major on major.institutionID = institution.institutionID
    INNER JOIN class on class.majorID = major.majorID
    INNER JOIN student on student.classID = class.classID 
WHERE institution.institutionName == CMI && student.gender == boy;
```

Comment: change the && to AND, && is not sql syntax, you almost might have to wrap CMI in 'CMI' and boy in 'boy'

Comment: The **`==`** is also not a valid operator. Valid operators are documented here: [http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/table-of-operators-HA010235862.aspx](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/table-of-operators-HA010235862.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `where` clause to this:

```
WHERE institution.institutionName = "CMI" AND student.gender = "boy";
```

In MS Access, `&` is for string concatenation.  I assume the error is because a string is expected between the two `&`s.

Answer (score 0):

use the word AND instead of && in your where clause

Comment: Also, string literals should be enclosed in quotes, and the **`==`** is not a valid operator.